# Start emiting values after custom event

Tags: rx-java

I have a background task and a few `Observable`s that are subscribed while this task is in progress. I want these observables to start emiting values only after background task finish. My first idea was to use `Observable.create()` and some blocking mechanism inside it to wait for the task. But I'm wondering if there is an rx-operator to do this.

Comment: do you need to start listening to the events after the task is done, or do you need to get the events and wait before until the task is over?

Comment: @Elyran, let's say that each of Observables is some network request. And I want them to start executing these requests only after background task is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` when the `background task completed`

```
Observable.create({
    ->
    // doing background task...
})
.onSubscribe(Schedules.newThread())
.flatMap(() -> getOtherObservable())
.subscribe(() -> {
    // onNext...
});

private Observable getOtherObservable(){
    // return other Observable
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: It's a good approach for a single observable, but I have a few that must react simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to the network requests in the `onCompleted` method.
the Observables will only start to emit values once they have a subscriber.

there is no need to be blocking here - just do the next thing you need when the first is completed

Edit: you don't have to do the actual subscribing in the same method
you can return an observable that is created from the result of the task
and then the client which does the subscribe should do it on the `onCompleted` of your observable. that's the idea of returning an Observable - you don't need to wait for the task to complete.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't suit my case, subscriptions are happening in client classes and I must return Observable object.